# Select sum of top three scores for each user

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I am having trouble writing a query for the following problem. I have tried some existing queries but cannot get the results I need.

I have a results table like this:

```
userid  score timestamp
1       50    5000
1       100   5000 
1       400   5000 
1       500   5000 
2       100   5000 
3       1000  4000
```

The expected output of the query is like this:

```
userid  score
3       1000
1       1000
2       100
```

I want to select a top list where I have n best scores summed for each user and if there is a draw the user with the lowest timestamp is highest. I really tried to look at all old posts but could not find one that helped me.

Here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT sum(score) FROM (
   SELECT score 
   FROM results 
   WHERE userid=1 ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 3
) as subquery
```

This gives me the results for one user, but I would like to have one query that fetches all in order.

Comment: There are only ever a maximum of 3 scores per user, so what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a pretty typical [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem. When I see those, I usually use a correlated subquery like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable m
WHERE(
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM myTable mT
  WHERE mT.userId = m.userId AND mT.score >= m.score) <= 3;
```

This is not the whole solution, as it only gives you the top three scores for each user in its own row. To get the total, you can use `SUM()` wrapped around that subquery like this:

```
SELECT userId, SUM(score) AS totalScore
FROM(
  SELECT userId, score
  FROM myTable m
  WHERE(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM myTable mT
    WHERE mT.userId = m.userId AND mT.score >= m.score) <= 3) tmp
GROUP BY userId;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e9c9/2) example.

**EDIT**

Regarding the ordering (which I forgot the first time through), you can just order by totalScore in descending order, and then by MIN(timestamp) in ascending order so that users with the lowest timestamp appears first in the list. Here is the updated query:

```
SELECT userId, SUM(score) AS totalScore
FROM(
  SELECT userId, score, timeCol
  FROM myTable m
  WHERE(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM myTable mT
    WHERE mT.userId = m.userId AND mT.score >= m.score) <= 3) tmp
GROUP BY userId
ORDER BY totalScore DESC, MIN(timeCol) ASC;
```

and here is an updated [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8e9c9/4) link.

**EDIT 2**

As JPW pointed out in the comments, this query will not work if the user has the same score for multiple questions. To settle this, you can add an additional condition inside the subquery to order the users three rows by timestamp as well, like this:

```
SELECT userId, SUM(score) AS totalScore
FROM(
  SELECT userId, score, timeCol
  FROM myTable m
  WHERE(
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM myTable mT
    WHERE mT.userId = m.userId AND mT.score >= m.score 
      AND mT.timeCol <= m.timeCol) <= 3) tmp
GROUP BY userId
ORDER BY totalScore DESC, MIN(timeCol) ASC;
```

I am still working on a solution to find out how to handle the scenario where the userid, score, and timestamp are all the same. In that case, you will have to find another tiebreaker. Perhaps you have a primary key column, and you can choose to take a higher/lower primary key?

Comment: Thanks McAdam331. I just added the order by and it wroks perfectly.

Comment: @Markus glad I could help. If this is the solution you use, feel free to accept it by clicking the checkmark next to the answer so future readers will know what solved your problem.

Comment: Try inserting an additional row with `1       100   5000` and see what happens.

Comment: Also, small comment, try to avoid using `timestamp` as a column name, because it is also a type in MySQL and can sometimes be confusing to read.

Comment: @jpw if we make the assumption the results table only has three columns, MySQL shouldn't let you insert a row like that, right? However, SQL Fiddle does and it does break my query, so I will try to find a solution for that.

Comment: I changed the names of the table cause tehy were in finnish thats why timestamp. Could think of a better name ;)

Comment: @Markus if a user has the same score on two questions, do you want the one with a lower timestamp? Also, if they have the same score and same timestamp, do you care how that tie is broken?

Comment: @jpw thank you for pointing out that flaw, I have edited my answer to the best that I can for now.

Comment: Either I'm missing something or is this not to complicate a rather simple query. Best practice is to only use subqueries if really necessary.

Comment: Actually I was missing something. Thought it was the highest 3 users.

Comment: @EmilIngerslev That makes sense. I was sitting here scratching my head the whole time trying to think of another way to do this. I'm sure there is, but I don't *think* mine is terribly inefficient.

Comment: Another tiebreaker would be the highest single score. Efficiency is not the key issua but Im wiling to learn better ways if there are some. And thanks again McAdam331. I think I checked it answered now?

Comment: @Markus I don't think you have to worry about efficiency here.

Answer (score 0):

Query for selecting top three scores from table.

SELECT score FROM result
GROUP BY `id`
ORDER BY `score` DESC
LIMIT 3;

Comment: he want user list if 2 users have same score then it should be on lowest timestamp

Comment: I need to get top three scores for each user.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try this?

```
SELECT score FROM result GROUP BY id ORDER BY score DESC, timestamp ASC LIMIT 3;
```

if 2 users have same score then it will set order depends on time.

Comment: They want to get three scores per user, this will just return three rows all together.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery

```
SELECT r.userid,
(  SELECT sum(r2.score)
   FROM results r2
   WHERE r2.userid = r.userid 
   ORDER BY score DESC 
   LIMIT 3
) as sub
FROM result r
GROUP BY r.userid
ORDER BY sub desc
```

Comment: This is ok but the limit 3 does not limit at all. It takes all scores for that user.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it like this

```
SELECT SUM(score) as total, min(timestamp) as first, userid FROM scores
GROUP BY userid
ORDER BY total DESC, first ASC
```

This is way more efficient than sub queries. If you want to extract more fields than `userid`, then you need to add them to the `group by`.

This will of cause not limit the number of scores pr user, which indeed seems to require a subquery to solve.

Comment: Yes single values was quite easy but getting n values was the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Found a pretty solution with the rank() function, but rank() is sadly enough not supported by MySQL.